# Create a new variable by checking conditions on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python and just started to learn `pandas`. I want to create a new variable by checking conditions on multiple columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np
```

Let's say I have the following dataframe

```
d = {'CUSTNO':[123, 124, 125, 126], 'STATUS':['ACTIVE', 'NO', 'CANCEL', 'ACTIVE'], 'CANCEL':[np.nan, '2019-08-09', np.nan, '2019-09-17']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['CANCEL'] = df['CANCEL'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format = '%Y-%m-%d', errors = 'coerce'))


 CUSTNO  STATUS      CANCEL
0   123  ACTIVE         NaT
1   124      NO  2019-08-09
2   125  CANCEL         NaT
3   126  ACTIVE  2019-09-17
```

The conditions that I would like to apply is as follows:

if `df['STATUS']` values are 'NO' or 'CANCEL' or `df['CANCEL']` contains date values: `HOLDING` will be set to 'N', Otherwise 'Y'.

The expected return as follows:

```
 CUSTNO  STATUS     CANCLE  HOLDING
0   123  ACTIVE        NaT        Y
1   124      NO 2019-08-09        N
2   125  CANCLE        NaT        N
3   126  ACTIVE 2019-09-17        N
```

Could you please give suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
c=df.STATUS.isin(['NO','CANCEL'])|df.CANCEL.notna()
df['HOLDING']=np.where(c,'N','Y')
```

---

```
   CUSTNO  STATUS     CANCEL HOLDING
0     123  ACTIVE        NaT       Y
1     124      NO 2019-08-09       N
2     125  CANCEL        NaT       N
3     126  ACTIVE 2019-09-17       N
```

Details:

```
#df.STATUS.isin(['NO','CANCEL']) #checks if STATUS is NO or CANCEL
#df.CANCEL.notna() #checks if CANCEL is not null and has a date
c=df.STATUS.isin(['NO','CANCEL'])|df.CANCEL.notna()
```

---

```
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Then we use [`np.where`](https://www.google.com/search?q=np+where&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&oq=np+where&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j0l3j69i60.1209j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to assign `N` where c is True, else `Y`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
>>> df["HOLDING"]=df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series({"HOLDING": "N" if x.STATUS=="NO" or isinstance(x.CANCEL, np.datetime64) else "Y"}), axis=1)
>>> df
      CANCEL  CUSTNO  STATUS HOLDING
0        NaT     123  ACTIVE       Y
1 2019-08-09     124      NO       N
2        NaT     125  CANCEL       Y
3 2019-09-17     126  ACTIVE       Y
```